# Jax-ws Vs Spring-ws client

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client, spring-ws

I am currently trying out Spring-ws and Jax-ws client for consuming a webservice. I have very limited knowledge in this area. For Spring-ws, I am using Jaxb2 plugin to generate the Java classes from WSDL. For Jax-ws client I am using wsdl2java maven plugin for generate Java classes.

As far as I have seen with Jax-ws we get even services classes generated by plugin, where in from Jaxb2 plugin I am only seeing the classes for soap body being generated. And with Spring WS we need to give explicitly few information for example SOAP action.

I would be grateful if any pointers to the use cases for Spring-ws vs Jax-ws.  For web services I have found good pointers which I have presented below and it gives great information.

https://dzone.com/articles/web-services-jax-ws-vs-spring

What does Jax-ws and spring-ws hold in case we are using them for configuring web service client?

Comment: I have referred to the series (3 part series) myself: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3209654/java-language/web-services-in-java-se-part-1-tools-overview.html. I hope its useful for you.

Comment: Thank you @sette. That helps with some part of the question. But still why Jax-ws vs spring-ws is still to be looked into.